# If $f$ is a polynomial, is $\{ \sin ( f(n)) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ dense in $[-1,1]$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irrational-numbers

If $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$, and $f$ is not a constant function, will $\{\sin f(n)\}^{+\infty}_{n=1}$ always be dense in $[-1,1]$? I think the key part is that whether $f(n)\alpha-[f(n)\alpha]$ is dense in $[0,1]$, here $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$, $\alpha \in \mathbb Q^c$, $[f(n)\alpha]$ means the biggest integer smaller than $f(n)\alpha$.

All the literature I can found is about the case of $\{\sin n\}^{+\infty}_{n=1}$, it is said that $n\alpha-[n\alpha]$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ for any given irrational number $\alpha$. I guess $f(n)\alpha-[f(n)\alpha]$ will be no longer distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$, but it seems that $f(n)\alpha-[f(n)\alpha]$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

I also found some books about continued fraction, but I am not sure whether they are related to my question. I would also be appreciated if anyone can tell me the name of related research. Right now I even don't know the keyword I should use in google scholar.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to something more like, "If $f$ is a polynomial, is $\sin f(n)$ dense in $[-1,1]$?"

Comment: Here is a link to some pretty advanced maths about the topic https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/

Comment: Well $f(n)=1$ is a polynomial, yet no density there... You need to restrict constants.

Comment: this is a classic theorem (of Weyl and fairly easily proven by induction starting from the well known result in degree $1$) which holds for any nonconstant $f$ with at least one coefficient $a_k$ in degree $1$ or higher s.t $a_k/(2\pi)$ is irrational - the classic theorem states that a polynomial $P$ with an irrational coefficient in degree $1$ or higher has $P(n)$ equidistributed modulo $1$ and by writing $f(n)= 2\pi f(n)/(2 \pi)$ we get that $f(n)$ is equidistributed modulo $2 \pi$ (which obviously implies the required result) when $f(n)/(2 \pi)$ is equidistributed modulo $1$